# How to exclude api.php from the default routing in htaccess

Tags: apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I use the default .httaccess provided by Zend. I have another route defined in my apache configs so that everything submitted to /api.php/WHATEVER is being routed to another framework.

If I add the default routes into the .htaccess file, this rule is being overwritten. What I tried to do to disable the rewrite engine was the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
# api.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(api\.php/.*)$
# Existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
# Existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
# Symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately, I don't see the error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should work on your accept-rate.....!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
# api.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(api\.php/.*)$
RewriteRule  api.php?(.*) [R=301,L]
# Existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
# Existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
# Symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

but you may adapt...